# Different python versions in conda env and why only one works with a package

Tags: python, conda, nba-api

I am doing a side project with sports and using the package nba-api. One of the functions/APIs it includes is a get_players() function. This should return all players in the NBA or null if the call does not work. While first trying this in my conda env with Python 3.10 installed it did not work. I tried without the conda env activated and with my system python version which is 3.11 and it did work. So I changed the version in my conda env. My question is, why did the conda env with Python 3.10 not work? Is it because of the difference between my system's Python version and the conda env? Or could it be a limit of the function/API?